# pandas groupby and use numbers between the different types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let say I have a df like this:

```
client   order_type    amount
John     Buy           100
John     Sell          100
Jeff     Buy           100
Jeff     Buy           100
Aaron    Buy           100
Aaron    Sell          100
Aaron    Buy           100
```

if I do:

```
df.groupby(['client','order_type'])['amount'].sum()
```

I would get something like:

```
John    Buy   100
        Sell  100
Jeff    Buy   100
        Sell  100
Aaron   Buy   200
        Sell  100
```

How to get something like Buy - Sell column in new dataframe:

```
Name      NetBuy
John      0
Jeff      200
Aaron     100
```

Comment: Shouldn't jeff have 200? 2x buy = 100 + 100?

Comment: edited. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map your order_type to a sign, there are many ways to do this, but the easiest to read in my opinion would be this:

```
df['sign'] = [1 if x == 'Buy' else -1 for x in df.order_type]
df['amount_adj'] = df.sign*df.amount
df.groupby(['client'])['amount_adj'].sum()
```

Output:

```
client
Aaron    100
Jeff     200
John       0
```

Same result using a one-liner and the faster `np.where`:

```
df = df.assign(amount=np.where(df.order_type.eq('Sell'), 
          df.amount*-1, df.amount)).groupby(['client'])['amount'].sum()
```

output:

```
client
Aaron    100
Jeff     200
John       0
```

Comment: Can use `np.where` instead of a list comprehension. Way quicker ;}

Comment: Yes and given low score of OP I went for the ugly-but-easy-to-understand path :)

Comment: Come-on, from all numpy methods, `np.where` is the most intuitive ! Can add both I think

Comment: there's another answer with `np.where` implemented, I think there's little value for me to add it, would you agree? I do appreciate your feedback :)

Comment: can you edit the ans to include df  = df.assign, thanks

Comment: sure thing, just did

Answer (score 1):

First cast your `sell` values to negative, then use `groupby.sum`:

```
df['amount'] = np.where(df['order_type'].eq('Sell'), -df['amount'], df['amount'])

df.groupby('client', as_index=False)['amount'].sum()
```

---

```
  client  amount
0  Aaron     100
1   Jeff     200
2   John       0
```

Comment: this led to SettingWithCopyWarning

Comment: Are you sure? We are not copying any data from one dataframe to another, does this not happen somewhere else in your code? @lrh09

Comment: Yup. I got this: 
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead